# CPU Governor broke on upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: upgrade, power-management, cpu, governor

Since upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10, my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 730S)'s CPU governor has been a mess. I use CPU Power Manager GNOME Extension to manage it, but the setting I choose doesn't hold since I upgraded and it fluctuates between the setting and powersave. Removing the extension and associated scripts (cpufreqctl and policykit rule) makes it default to powersave, which I can feel.

I've tried cpufreq as well but the setting doesn't hold and it reverts to powersave.

Does anyone know how I can set it to always be like ondemand or performance? Or even just the default functionality? Basically anything but powersave (it's always plugged in). I'd like to be able to use CPU Power Manager extension again, ideally.

It's not hot and the fans are running lowspeed.

I also want to make sure things aren't competing to set the governor as that's what I think is causing the fluctuations.

EDIT: CPU frequency scaling driver:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy6/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy7/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
```

Thank you for helping me work though this. I didn't see any changes on the `watch` window - it stayed saying "performance" for each core.
I had `turbostat` up for like half an hour or so. Here's the output https://pastebin.com/g3dA2vUQ

Comment: It would help to know which CPU scaling driver you are using. The meaning of the 'powersave` governor is different if the driver is intel_pstate in active mode verses the acpi-cpufreq and intel_cpufreq, and maybe others, drivers. Do `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_driver`. I can help you, but only with primitive commands, I never ever use higher level stuff (well, sometimes thermald). By the way, the `ondemand` governor does not exist for the intel_pstate driver in active mode.

Comment: ```/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy6/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy7/scaling_driver:intel_pstate```
I have seen about intel_pstate

Comment: For the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver there is only the `powersave` and `performance` governors. For most users the `powersave` governor provides sufficient responsiveness, and is similar to the acpi-cpufreq CPU scaling driver using the `ondemand` or `scheutil` governors. It is also a function of if your processor has HWP (HardWare P-state) control or not.

Comment: @DougSmythies That's similar to what I was reading, but it's not what's happening. It's quite sluggish even on Firefox browsing with 2 tabs (Gmail and this one), which is absolutely not how it behaved under 20.04. (I've checked htop - nothing seems abnormal there).
I know turbo boost occasionally gets triggered because I can feel the difference even in the mouse cursor. It'll literally change speed while moving it and is very unnatural... 
Do you think multiple things are trying to set the governor?

Comment: I do not know if multiple things are trying to set the governor, perhaps watch it to observe. Say, `watch --interval 5 grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor` It seems more like either an issue with graphics (which I know nothing about) or some sort of CPU throttling. Suggest to always run turbostat on some terminal window, observing. Say, `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6`.

Comment: Your turbostat data does not make sense in some spots. Yes, the CPU frequency should be higher, for example in line 37. The CPU temperature is rather high in sample 167. I do not understand sample 232.

Comment: Is your processor a i7-8565U? Seems 1.8Ghz is the non-turbo max CPU frequency. suggest to watch the turbo enable/disable setting. Do: `watch cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`. Was there a suspend between your turbostat samples 231 and 232?

Comment: I suspect your issue is whatever thermal monitoring utility oscillating. Also watch the maximum CPU frequency setting, `watch grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*` will let you monitor both the turbo enable and max and others at the same time.

Comment: Any followup about your issue?

Comment: Yes. So I watched `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*` yesterday. It commonly sets the max_freq to 8%. Then when I have lots of things open, it turns on Turbo. I assume it scales the max_freq up after? But in order to do things, I have to manually set the governor high (CPU Power Manager GNOME Ext) or it'll just feel stuck. As for oscillating, it does not appear to happen. It seems the biggest thing is that it keeps max_freq 8-10% for a lot of the time. Also meant to mention that I don't think I had suspended in sample 232 yesterday but wanted a bit more to report first.

Comment: you are saying that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` is getting set to 8? And turbo is constantly changing between enabled and disabled (0 and 1, respectively)? Are there any temperature related messages in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: If it were me, I would stop using and uninstall the "CPU Power Manager GNOME Ext" you mentioned.

Comment: That's correct. `max_perf_pct` goes to 8. I uninstalled CPU Power Manager just now to try, but I'm hesitant because should it go back to 8, it becomes pretty frustrating to use the computer. I had also tried it before posting, but this time I made sure it got rid of all config files and everything. Let's see though. Thanks again for helping and being patient. 

As for syslog, there are some temp readings but nothing higher than 34C. In kernlog, the only temp related message is just the kernel linking the `x86_pkg_temp_thermal` module.

Comment: The primitive to set it: `echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`.

Comment: Rebooted to make sure everything extension related wasn't there. But I ended up having to use the line to set max_perf_pct pretty quick. I was watching YouTube and max_perf_pct was 8-10%, so it is changing, but not enough/correctly. The YouTube video (both video and sound) was stuttering extremely badly. After setting it to 100, it ran like it's supposed to.

Comment: Update for day later: Runs well after setting max_perf_pct to 100, but every like hour or so (not a consistent amount of time, might be 2 hr sometimes), it'll go back to 8. The laptop is plugged in at all times and temps are not hot. I set it back to 100 each time to be able to use.

Comment: Well, something is mis-configured somewhere, but i don't know where. Perhaps, and just for a test, try the acpi-cpufreq CPU scaling driver or the intel_cpufreq (intel_pstate in passive mode) driver with HWP disabled.

Comment: Probably will be a few days before I try that, but will do. Really unsure why upgrading would've done something like this though as I've looked through the package list and nothing stuck out that would have changed CPU scaling.

Comment: One thing that's started happening is that something will crash if I open another application and it starts going slow. Oftentimes it's gnome-shell, sometimes it's discord, manytimes it's password and keys. Seems random just to free up resources.

Comment: So this is still a very annoying issue. I've been using my Windows partition a little more often because I haven't figured out. However, while the temps don't go too high, I did notice that the fan speeds on Windows are much higher when doing a similar amount of things. I'm going to try manually setting the fan speed high. 
Any ideas of what would cause the fan speed to be so low after the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be fixed by upgrading to 21.04.

*shrug* no clue why/how/what but it's definitely not throttling the CPU after I upgraded today.

It will be nice to not have to manually set the min/max perf pct settings every few hours.